# How to set a scroll in a comboboxtext

Tags: ruby, gtk, gtk3

When I use comboboxtext with a lot of options, I can see that there is no scroll. I can go up and down with the mouse, moving it or with the central button, but the typical scroll widget to move faster up and down does not appear anywhere.

How can I make the scroll widget appear in the options of the comboboxtext?

```
require 'gtk3'

Material2 = Gtk::ComboBoxText.new()
for i in (0..100)
  string = "material " + i.to_s
  Material2.append_text(string)
end
$MenuPrincipal = Gtk::Table.new(60, 60, true)
$MenuPrincipal.attach(Material2, 0, 60, 0, 10, $options, $options, 0, 0)
$window = Gtk::Window.new
$options = Gtk::AttachOptions::EXPAND | Gtk::AttachOptions::SHRINK
$window.add($MenuPrincipal)
$window.show_all
Gtk.main
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any code for context here?

Comment: require 'gtk3'
Material2 = Gtk::ComboBoxText.new()
for i in (0..100)
   string = "material " + i.to_s
   Material2.append_text(string)
end
$MenuPrincipal = Gtk::Table.new(60, 60, true)
$MenuPrincipal.attach(Material2, 0, 60, 0, 10, $options, $options, 0, 0)
$window = Gtk::Window.new
$options = Gtk::AttachOptions::EXPAND | Gtk::AttachOptions::SHRINK
$window.add($MenuPrincipal)
$window.show_all
Gtk.main

Comment: require 'gtk3'

Material2 = Gtk::ComboBoxText.new()

for i in (0..100)

   string = "material " + i.to_s

   Material2.append_text(string)

end


$MenuPrincipal = Gtk::Table.new(60, 60, true)


$MenuPrincipal.attach(Material2, 0, 60, 0, 10, $options, $options, 0, 0)


$window = Gtk::Window.new

$options = Gtk::AttachOptions::EXPAND | Gtk::AttachOptions::SHRINK

$window.add($MenuPrincipal)

$window.show_all

Gtk.main

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get how to properly edit code format in this comments. You will see how this code creates a comboboxtext with a lot of options, which I can select with the mouse, moving it or using the center button; but there is no scroll widget

Comment: It's better to edit your question and add the code there where formatting is easy. In the comments no matter how hard you try it will always be jumbled up as a single line.

Comment: If this is Ruby code it's unusual to see a whole lot of global variables like `$window`. Remember in Ruby that `$` means global, not variable as in PHP.

Comment: I thought that you would wonder about the global variables and the programming style. I know that it is not usual and neither best, but it works for me and it is easier for me to understand.

Nevertheless, my issue is not the global variables but the not knowing how to tell the comboboxtext to show a scroll. I would be very pleased if you can help me on that one.

Comment: Global variables are usually hugely problematic in all but the smallest programs, and in small programs they're not necessary. The reason I point this out is it's an extremely damaging habit to get into and you need to nip this in the bud right away. Ruby's class structure makes it easy to use instance variables that are contained within objects, so consider wrapping this in a simple class and using `@window` instead, etc. Globals "work" if you have just one thing, but as soon as you have two instances they fight over the same variables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it is not the point of my question. Can you help me with scrolling the options of the combobox?

Comment: Not sure I can help you with that. Ruby + GTK is a fairly rare combination, as GTK itself is relatively rare on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change (or add) line in the css style:

```
* {   
  -GtkComboBox-appears-as-list: 1; 
}
```

If you don't have control over user's style see my answer about [modifying labels' style from code (example is in python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42788299/1981374).

I have not found how to achieve it without modifying style but maybe there is some hidden gem in ruby bindings.